# Is sample path of Brownian Motion deterministic?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider a standard continuous Brownian Motion $B_t(\omega): \Omega \times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$, where: $B_0(\omega) = 0$; $B_t(\omega)$ has stationary independent increments; $B_t-B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$. Then what can we say about the sample path of a Brownian Motion? In my point of view, a sample path is such that we fix $\omega = \omega_0 \in \Omega$ and get a function $B(\omega_0,t)$, and we plot the graph of that function with respect to $t$. If so, can we say that $\textbf{a sample path is deterministic}$? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: yes of course. But that is not what people mean when they say sample path

Comment: @Andrew Then what do you call definition I mentioned? And what is a sample path? Thanks!

Comment: Once you fix $\omega$ it is usually referred to as a realization of said random element. Here, "realization of $B$." The sample paths of a continuous time process $X = (X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ usually refers to the map $\omega \mapsto X(\omega) \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb R_+}$

Answer (score 2):

What you have said is literally true, but is misleading, and shows confusion about what is meant by the term "sample path".

A "sample path" is not, in itself, a mathematical object; it is not a path or a function or a number or anything like that.  Rather, any sentence involving the phrase "sample path" is just a slightly informal way of expressing a more formal  statement about a certain event having probability 1.

For instance, when we say "A Brownian motion sample path is 1/4-Hölder continuous", what we really mean is the following.  Let $A$ be the set of all outcomes $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is 1/4-Hölder continuous; that is
$$A = \left\{ \omega \in \Omega : \sup_{s,t \in [0,T]} \frac{|B_t(\omega) - B_s(\omega)|}{|t-s|^{1/4}} < \infty\right\}.$$
Then "A Brownian motion sample paths is 1/4-Hölder continuous" should be understood as the assertion that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$; i.e. $A$ happens almost surely.

It may help to rephrase "sample path" as "generic path" or "typical path".  It does not refer to any specific path; it makes a statement about the set of paths as a whole, and how prevalent among them are paths with a certain property.  For example, a statement like "the typical American eats between 50 and 100 hamburgers per year" does not give us any information about any particular American, but it tells us something about the set of Americans.

And describing a sample path as *deterministic* is rather nonsensical on another level.  To use an analogy from lower-level mathematics, think of a function like $f(x)=x^2$.  Your saying that "$B_t(\omega_0, t)$ is deterministic" is like saying "$f(5)$ is constant".   Okay, well, $f(5)$ is the number $25$, which is not a function of $x$, so in that sense $f(5)$ is a constant.  But when people use the word "constant", they mean that some object that might *potentially* depend on $x$, does not actually depend on it.  So it doesn't really make much sense to say "$f(5)$ is constant" because there is no *possibility* for $f(5)$ to depend on $x$; substituting in $5$ got rid of $x$.  Such a statement is literally true, but also totally pointless to say.

A statement like "$B(\omega_0, t)$ is deterministic" is similarly pointless.  "Deterministic" means that something which potentially might depend on $\omega$, does not actually depend on it.  But obviously $B_t(\omega_0, t)$ does not depend on $\omega$, because you just replaced $\omega$ by $\omega_0$. So what you said has no useful content.

Comment: Brownian motion can be viewed as the coordinate map on the space $\Omega=C(\mathbb R_+)$ equipped with the Wiener measure. As such, every sample path $\omega$ is a well-defined object (a continuous function) and IMHO nothing is pointless about describing it as deterministic. From that point of view OP's question is fully analogous to "is every number in $\{1,...,n\}$ deterministic when we equip that set with a uniform distribution?" The answer depends on what that number is to OP: randomly chosen or not.

Comment: ... I can't find a better wording. But I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: Not really I'm afraid.  I would say the quoted question in your comment is similarly "pointless" to OP's, and to my "$f(5)$ is constant" example.  I don't see how to answer your question in a way that conveys any nontrivial information.  Brownian motion, like any stochastic process, is of course a function on some sample space $\Omega$, and I don't see how it makes any difference to take $\Omega$ to be $C(\mathbb{R}_+)$ as in your example, versus any other arbitrary set.

Comment: @KurtG. I agree that for *each* $\omega$, $B_t(\omega)$ represents a path on $[0,T]$, and if you like, you may choose $\Omega$ so that they are all continuous.  Every one of those *paths* is a well-defined object.  But the phrase "sample path" does not refer to any one of them.  Much as every single person in the world is a "well-defined person", but the phrase "typical person" does not refer to any one of them.

Comment: I never had to distinguish between "path" and "sample path". Suppose we did that and define the path $\omega$ as an element of $\Omega$ (without any reference to probability) then it is deterministic (how could it not be?). If we consider the "sample path" being a random variable it is not deterministic. Seems we agree but I like it *terse*.

Comment: For me, "sample path" is critically different from "path" by itself.  If not, then how do you interpret the phrase "Sample paths of Brownian motion are Holder-1/4 continuous"?  Under most constructions, it isn't going to be true of *every* path, yet still it ought to express an important truth.  Another phrasing would be "Almost every path of Brownian motion is Holder-1/4 continuous" - it is not a statement about all paths, nor about any specific path.  Just like "almost every real number is irrational".

Comment: @KurtG.: The way "sample path" is used in the literature is certainly equivalent to what I wrote in my third paragraph, meaning roughly the same as "almost every".  I don't know of any way to define "sample path" as a mathematical object that would yield that interpretation - not as a path, not as a random variable, etc.

Comment: I don't disagree on that. The literature I grew up with mostly used $\mathbb P$-almost every path.  Long live "sample path" ! :)